# Which directories should be excluded when backing up the root directory using ubuntu?

Tags: backup, root, duplicity

I use duplicity to backup the root in ubuntu:

`sudo duplicity --no-encryption   --exclude /proc  /  file:///Path_to_Backup_folder`

I receive the following errors:

`Error Operation not permitted getting delta for /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/...`

`Error Invalid argument getting delta for /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/free_buffer`

Should I exclude `\sys` from the backup?

In general, which directories should be excluded when backup the root directory?

Comment: @muru I just ran another backup using the options provided by this link. I wait to see if the back will finish successfully, and then answer your question.

Comment: @muru, yes this link answered my question.